# Is there a way to access an object of an NSMutableArray using Swift?

Tags: swift, nsmutablearray

My group and I are writing a space shooter game. We store the player and hazards in and NSMutableArray called objects. I just finished writing a function to control the players movement using tilt controls, but to test it I need to pass in the player when I call the function and I can't seem to access the player from the objects array. Here's my code:

```
public var objects: NSMutableArray!

objects.add(Player(pos: GLKVector3(v: (0.0, 0.0, -5.0)), up: GLKVector3(v: (0.0, 1.0, 0.0)), forw: GLKVector3(v: (0.0, 0.0, -1.0)), hp: 5, dmg: 1));
        objects.add(Satellite(pos: GLKVector3(v: (2.0, -2.0, -40.0)), up: GLKVector3(v: (0.0, 1.0, 0.0)), forw: GLKVector3(v: (0.0, 0.0, -1.0)), hp: 5, dmg: 1, spd: 2.0));
        objects.add(Satellite(pos: GLKVector3(v: (-2.0, 2.0, -50.0)), up: GLKVector3(v: (0.0, 1.0, 0.0)), forw: GLKVector3(v: (0.0, 0.0, 1.0)), hp: 1, dmg: 1, spd: 2.0));

myDeviceMotion(objects.object(at: 0));
```

Comment: If you are programming in swift then _do not_ use NSMutableArray, use the native Array type instead.

Answer (score 0):

Not use NSMutableArray, user Arrays and pass temp Protocol to your classes.

```
protocol MyTempProtocol {  }

class Player: MyTempProtocol {
    // ...
}

class Satellite: MyTempProtocol {
    // ...
}

/// --------------
let player1 = Player()
let player2 = Player()
let satellite1 = Satellite()
let satellite2 = Satellite()

var objects = [MyTempProtocol]()
objects.append(player1)
objects.append(satellite1)
objects.append(satellite2)
objects.append(player2)


if let objectIsPlayer = objects[0] is Player {
    // ...
} else if let objectIsSatellite = objects[0] is Satellite {
    // ... 
} else {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: No need for a custom protocol in this case, use `Any` instead

Comment: Any was not type-safe enough, you can put everything into that array like Bool, String, Structs, UIView and so on. Use custom protocol to handle little access control inside your array.

Comment: And you can let anything conform to `MyTempProtocol` like Bool, String and so on so there is little gain since you will always have to do the check with `is` anyway. A little more clarity yes but also more to maintain.